# Google Tag Manager container changes only show for some users

Tags: google-tag-manager

I published changes to a GTM container for an HTML tag update (an interim fix for our website to update phone number links to E164 format). This tag already existed to update the phone number links, but not in E164 format.

I'm seeing the updated HTML tag version on various devices, browsers, etc. Some other testers are seeing the updates, as well. However, some users are still seeing the old version of the tag. These users have cleared cache and cookies, used incognito browsers, etc. and have used different devices and browsers.

These changes were made about two weeks ago so I don't believe this is a caching issue.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the tester to check their GTM version is the same as your's first

1. Check your version of the GTM
   [image]
2. How to check the GTV version on the devtool request.
   [image]
3. If the version is the same. Try to add some console on the html tag and share the preview link with them.